# How to combine multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to combine multidimension array

```
<?php

$array[0] = [1=>[2=>[4=>[20=>""]]]];
$array[1] = [1=>[2=>[5=>[21=>""]]]];
$array[2] = [1=>[2=>[5=>[22=>""]]]];
$array[3] = [1=>[2=>[5=>[23=>""]]]];
$array[4] = [1=>[2=>[5=>[25=>""]]]];
$array[5] = [3=>[9=>[12=>[33=>""]]]];
$array[6] = [3=>[9=>[12=>[34=>""]]]];
$array[7] = [3=>[9=>[12=>[38=>""]]]];

?>
```

how to convert to be like:

```
$arrays = [1=>[2=>[4=>[20=>""],5=>[21=>"",22=>"",25=>""]]],[3=> [9 => [12 => [33 => "",38 => ""]]]]];
```

I am tried using array_merge :

```
$arrays = [];

    foreach ($array as $val)
    {
        $arrays = array_merge($arrays,$val);

    }
```

but the result always the first dimension make increment by that self

I already tried some func(like  $arrays = $arrays+$val,array_push etc
) since 2 month ago I thought use array_merge is fine but the issue is make increment by that self  so I am still not found the solution, I was also search on google and still no found about this.

Comment: Please show some effort by editing your question and explain what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Well, that must be a homework.. you can achieve that simply by using  `array_map` or `foreach`

Comment: @Clijsters i edited , thanks for help me

Comment: @VuralAcar can you give some clue?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur What is not a clue about Vural's comment? It exactly says what you have to do to get what you want.

Comment: I don't know why this question got downvote even if I already given my effort and this question is not duplicated to other question as far I searched since 2 month ago,  and the commentators also give homework with wrong clue because the answer is simply using built PHP built in function which I never knew before. 
@Clijsters

Comment: To make it more clear: What makes you think, that **I** downvoted it?

Comment: @Clijsters I though you downvoted cause my post look no efort, I update the effort but  someone still downvoted this post again. I though this was very clear because i given the input and the output what I wanted. So where part is not clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the built-in array functions `array_merge_recursive` or `array_replace_recursive`. The code looks like:

```
$arrays = [];

foreach ($array as $val)
{
    $arrays = array_replace_recursive($arrays,$val);

}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Comment: I already tried array_merge_recursive before and the result is just same like array_merge, but array_replace_recursive is work perfectly, thank you so much